# How to fix "Jest encountered an unexpected token" while integrating Jest with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am trying to integrate Jest with my TypeScipt project but getting `TypeError: Reflect.hasOwnMetadata is not a function` error.

[image]

References:

- https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel
- https://javascript.plainenglish.io/beginners-guide-to-testing-jest-with-node-typescript-1f46a1b87dad

This is what I have tried so far:

- Installed following packages:

  - `npm install --save-dev jest`
  - `npm install --save-dev @types/jest`
  - `npm install --save-dev ts-jest`
- My `jest.config.ts` file

  ```
  module.exports = {
    transform: {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    },
    testMatch: ["**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)"],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/lib/", "/node_modules/"],
    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
    collectCoverage: true,
    roots: [
      "<rootDir>/src", // informs jest of the root dir
    ],
    coverageThreshold: {
      global: {
        branches: 80,
        functions: 80,
        lines: 80,
        statements: 80,
      },
    },
  };
  ```
- My `package.json` file

  ```
  "scripts": {
      "test": "jest --coverage --color"
    },
  ```
- My sample test file

  ```
  describe("HealthService", () => {
      let healthService: HealthService;

      beforeEach(async () => {
          healthService = new HealthService();
      });

      it("Success", async () => {
          const mockHealthCheckModel: HealthModel = {
              dateTime: new Date(),
              description: "Health Check",
              status: "Connected",
          }
          const output = await healthService.healthCheck();
          expect(output).toEqual(mockHealthCheckModel);

      });
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

After spending sometime, I figured out that if I add `import 'reflect-metadata';` in my `spec.ts` then it resolves the issue.

Now this means that I have to add this line on all my test files. I am trying to find if there is a way to configure this at one location rather than improting it on all test files. I'll update this answer once I figure that out.

i.e.:

**AR:**

```
import { HealthModel } from "../../models/health.model";
import HealthService from "../health.service";

describe("HealthService", () => {
    let healthService: HealthService;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        healthService = new HealthService();
    });

    it("Success", async () => {
        const mockHealthCheckModel: HealthModel = {
            dateTime: new Date(),
            description: "Health Check",
            status: "Connected",
        }
        const output = await healthService.healthCheck();
        expect(output).toEqual(mockHealthCheckModel);
    });
});
```

**ER:**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { HealthModel } from "../../models/health.model";
import HealthService from "../health.service";

describe("HealthService", () => {
    let healthService: HealthService;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        healthService = new HealthService();
    });

    it("Success", async () => {
        const mockHealthCheckModel: HealthModel = {
            dateTime: new Date(),
            description: "Health Check",
            status: "Connected",
        }
        const output = await healthService.healthCheck();
        expect(output).toEqual(mockHealthCheckModel);
    });
});
```